# Is there a function like next_permutation but for permutations with repetition?

Tags: c++, arrays, permutation, combinations, repeat

What I want to do is to find every permutation of a 1-d array with repetitions of its contents.

e.g.

```
int array[]={1,2,3};
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    next_permutation(array,array+3)
    for(int j=0;j<=3;j++){
        printf("%d ",array[j]);
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

will return:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
etc...
```

what I want the function to return:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
1 2 2
2 2 1
2 1 2
1 1 3
1 3 1
3 1 1
etc...
```

Is there a function that can do that?

Thanks in advance,
     Erik

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944508/arbitrary-digit-counter

Comment: and this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380962/generate-all-combinations-of-arbitrary-alphabet-up-to-arbitrary-length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not doing permutation but just counting.

Ex. if your enumerating set {0, 1} over 3 digits, you'll get:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

See, that's just binary counting.

So map your element set into n-digits, then do n-based count will give you the right awnser

Answer (score 0):

I had this written in Java.
Non optimized code, but you get the point:

```
String [] data = {"1","2","3"};
public void perm(int maxLength, StringBuffer crtComb){

    if (crtComb.length() == maxLength){
        System.out.println(crtComb.toString());
        return;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        crtComb.append(data[i]);
        perm(maxLength, crtComb);
        crtComb.setLength(crtComb.length()-1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general when computing permutations of integers from 1 to k (with repetition):

1. Initially set first permutation as 1 1 1 .... (k times).
2. Find the rightmost index (say j) such that the element at that index is less than k.
3. Increment the value of the element at index j by one, and from position j + 1 to k reset all elements to 1.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3.

Applying this logic, we now get:

1st permutation -> 1 1 1.

Then at position 2 (0 index counting), we have 1 < 3, so increment it and reset all elements after this to 1. 2nd permutation -> 1 1 2.

Then at position 1 (0 index counting), we have 1 < 3, so increment it and reset all elements after this to 1. 3rd permutation -> 1 2 1

And so on.